# Search for form element in database multiple times

Tags: php, postgresql

I am trying to learn php and came across a task which i have need help with.

> Background information - I have a postgresql database which has
>   multiple tables.
>
> What I need - When I enter anything in the form on my HTML page, i
>   need to extract all information from all the tables that contain
>   information related to what I have entered.
>
> Example - Suppose I enter food poisoning in the form. I need to access
>   all the tables and extract the different information related to food
>   poisoning.

```
My code: (the connection part is not being posted as it works fine)


    <?php
            $result = pg_prepare($dbh, "Query1", 'SELECT * FROM Project.bacteria WHERE disease = $1');
            // if (pg_numrows($result) == 0)    { 
                // $result = pg_prepare($dbh, "Query1", 'SELECT * FROM Project.virus WHERE disease = $1');  
            // }

            //$sql = "SELECT * FROM Project.bacteria WHERE disease=";
            //$result = pg_query($dbh, $sql);
            $result = pg_execute($dbh, "Query1", array($disease));
            if (!$result) {
                    die("Error in SQL query: " . pg_last_error());
            }
            //$rows = pg_fetch_all($result)

    /*// iterate over result set
    // print each row*/
                while ($row = pg_fetch_array($result)) {
                        echo $row[0]." ".$row[1]. "<br />";
                    } 
?>
```

For the above code, when I enter `food poisoning` it searches just one table i.e `bacteria` and returns the related information ( here as a test i have taken just information at `row position 1 and row position 2`.)

Since there are multiple tables, like a table `drugs` that stores information of drugs used to cure food poisoning, i would want to extract that information from the respective table.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I think you are looking for SQL's `union` operator.

Comment: i want to know that does all the table contains the column disease?

Answer (score 1):

try this one

```
SELECT * FROM bacteria WHERE disease = ''
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM drugs where desease = ''
```

but i think the best way is to normalize you tables. :)

Comment: I have different no of columns in the tables, can i do a right/left join with multiple tables?